# Piping rectangle region of text from vim to an external program?

Tags: vim

I am editing a large text array in vim, and I want to compute on one sub-column of it.

Simplified example of edited file:

```
name value name   saturation 
red  5     green  2
blue 7     yellow 7 
other text
```

I want to pipe column 4 through an external program calc.pl,
calc.pl replaces numbers with new numbers in the input, for example:

```
 name value name   saturation
 red  5     green  2.4
 blue 7     yellow 7.14
 other text
```

When I select rectangle in column 4, using v.motion, and !perl calc.pl
the whole lines gets piped to calc.pl, not just the rectangle.

A work around would be to: cut rectangle to temp file,
run calc.pl on temp file, and then read output as rectangle.

Is there a straight forward solution in vim, without having
to cut/shell/paste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the [vis](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195) plugin by Charles Campbell

> Use ctrl-v to select a column, then apply an external filter to that column. `ctrl-v ..move.. :B !sort`

Another plugin that might work for you is [NrrwRgn](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) by Christian Brabandt.

> Use :NarrowRegion to narrow a line based selection or alternatively visually select a range and press nr
>
> In the scratch buffer simply save it and the changes will be copied into the original file. 
>   This is only a very simple help. You should probably read the help, that is provided with the plugin. See :h NarrowRegion